# Get current monitor's size in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to get the size of the monitor where the cursor is currently. To do that I took the `MonitorFromPoint` function to get the monitor from the cursor point.

I have my code down below but it doesn't work properly, it returns 0 when getting the lRight property...

```
Private Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

Private Type RECT
    lLeft As Long
    lTop As Long
    lRight As Long
    lBottom As Long
End Type

Private Type MONITORINFO
    cbSize As Integer
    rcMonitor As RECT
    rcWork As RECT
    dwFlags As Integer
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function MonitorFromPoint Lib "user32.dll" (pt As POINTAPI, ByVal dwFlags As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetMonitorInfoA Lib "user32.dll" (hMonitor As LongPtr, lpmi As MONITORINFO) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As LongPtr

Private mPoint As POINTAPI

Sub test()

    GetCursorPos mPoint ' Get point from cursor current position
    Dim hMonitor As LongPtr, MI As MONITORINFO
    hMonitor = MonitorFromPoint(mPoint, 2)
    MI.cbSize = Len(MI)
    GetMonitorInfoA hMonitor, MI
    
    MsgBox MI.rcMonitor.lRight ' returns 0

End Sub
```